# Export git log to variable as multiline string

Tags: git, shell

When I execute this command

```
 git log 23237d...1a8815 --oneline --pretty=tformat:"%h %B"
```

I get something like

```
1a88151 commit1

8a544c0 commit2

b168aa9 commit3
```

But when I want to export this to some variable:

```
export LOG=`git log 23237d...1a8815 --oneline --pretty=tformat:"%h %B"`
```

And output it: `echo $LOG`, 
I get this:

```
1a88151 commit1 8a544c0 commit2 b168aa9 commit3
```

How can I make multiline export?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash processes the input using the contents of the `IFS` variable.  From the docs:

> The Internal Field Separator (IFS) that is used for word splitting after expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.
>   The default value is `<space><tab><newline>`.

You can change the values of `IFS` to alter the behaviour:

```
IFS='' export LOG=`git log 23237d...1a8815 --oneline --pretty=tformat:"%h %B"`
```

Comment: The problem with this solution, setting IFS to the empty string, is that it's misleading. The IFS='' doesn't affect the line that calls 'git log' and stores it in the LOG variable, but instead IFS='' affects the `echo $LOG` line, and also persists for the rest of the shell session, with weird an unexpected effects.

Comment: Try the following in your shell and note which ones display `y y y` and which ones preserve the newlines and output three lines of `y`: (1) `IFS=''; LOG=\`yes | head -n3\`; unset IFS; echo $LOG` (2) `unset IFS; LOG=\`yes | head -n3\`; IFS=''; echo $LOG` (3) `unset IFS; LOG=\`yes | head -n3\` ; echo "$LOG"`

Answer (score 9):

You need to quote the expansion of the `LOG` variable in the call to echo:

```
echo "$LOG"
```

This prevents word splitting from taking place.  You don't need to modify the `IFS` variable in this case.